# IdentityServer4 login api

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 to secure my API and also to authenticate users, the client is the main ASP.NET Core MVC App, I just want the login interface and UI to be at the MVC App and the login implementation at the IdentityServer, so the IdentityServer must have an API to just receive username and password from the MVC app login page return the token which will be used in cookies

Comment: I do not understand your question, but what I want to implement is to make the login views at the client, not at the identityserver
All examples provided in the documentation make the login views at the identityserver

Comment: @malballah I'd say if that's a requirement then `identityserver4` and OpenID Connect are not the right tool for that job. ASP.Net Identity should be adequate for your needs. If you insist on using an OIDC implementation then check out the "resource owner password" grant type - it's part of the protocol but its use is recommended against unless you meet very specific criteria. Give this a read: https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

Comment: @mackie What is the problem if I make users enter username and password in the client app (mvc or native) and send them to the identity server to authenticate the user, I like identityserver because it works with OpenId and oAuth2

Comment: @mackie forgot to say also I am the owner of the client and the identityserver service app

Comment: @mackie I think I got the idea why it is bad to use this grant type, my goal was indeed to save the time to used to maintain the login views in the identity server but it deserve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to move your views for several reasons. Some of them:

- If you move the views to your MVC client you will have to create those views in all your clients.
- OAuth2 / OpenId Connect should delegate authorization / authentication to your Idp to avoid [credentials sharing](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications). Instead of that, you are forced to use Resource Owner Password Credentials which implies that we cannot use the user's consent pages from the Idp.
- You won't have Autentication Cookie from your Idp for Single Sign On.

Comment: I got it, but what if I have a native app and I need to create a login screen for it, how users would login from native apps, like facebook app it allow you to enter your email and password?

Comment: _For authorizing users in native apps, the best current practice is to perform the OAuth authorization request in an external user-agent_ [BCP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp212). However, for first party apps you can use ROPC. It is very common to have several clients each with a different Grant. In your case you can use clients with Authorization Code grant for your MVC apps and other with ROPC for your native app.

Comment: @Alpha75 i agree with this reasons but site views are different than identity server. Is this be a reason to use an API between them ? I am also curious about your opinion and solution on this subject, thanks

Comment: You can define your own views in Identity Server (look and feel). Even use views depending on the client. I do not recommend this because the user trusts the authority and does not have to do it on the client (think of an authentication with Google in a window with the appearance of a third party, would you trust?). You can also use [ProxyKit](https://github.com/proxykit/ProxyKit) to "replicate" the views in an apigateway.