# IdentityServer4, Login through my web application login page

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have web application that currently uses IdentityServer4 Sign In page to login and to generate token etc.

I want to change the flow and want to use my web application Sign In page to get  login credentials and than seamlessly post/send the info to identityserver for authentication, token generation etc.

How can I achieve above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you have a pretty similar question (if not the same) [IdentityServer4 login api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560046/identityserver4-login-api/59566538#59566538)

Comment: @Alpha75 thanks for your comment. Actually in my case, my application login page will be posting username / password to identityserver for validation and further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use resource owner password grant :

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore1/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html

The OAuth 2.0 resource owner password grant allows a client to send username and password to the token service and get an access token back that represents that user.

But resource owner password grant only for "trusted" (or legacy) applications. And is not recommended for security reasons .

Comment: Thanks @Nan Yu. I also found a link for that may be helpful for others for post-registration sign-in with Identity Server. https://benfoster.io/blog/identity-server-post-registration-sign-in